# Creating a date filter in jinja2

Tags: python, mongodb, jinja2

I'm trying to work out the age of a record in my jinja2 with a filter. I created a simple filter in the following way. The date is stored in a mongodb field and its original form should be of the format of the python datetime object. Here is an example of the record:

```
 "date_update": {
        "$date": "2016-02-29T11:13:41.730Z"
    }, 


app.jinja_env.filters['record'] = lambda u: record(u)

def record(date_obj):
    print(date_obj)
    print(type(date_obj))
    return (datetime.datetime.today() - date_obj).days
```

I use the filter in the following way:

```
{{  myrec.date_update|record }}
```

If I look at the output, I see the following:

```
class 'jinja2.runtime.Undefined'
```

So my question is, how best should I deal with the dates in jinja2 in the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an unknown variable name within your template. From all you've posted so far, it is not clear whether you pass a variable `myrec` to the template renderer in the first place. So for better help, please post a minimal, self-contained example that exhibits the error.

Comment: That we my stupid error, field wasn't in the mongo projection!